# Which is correct in sentence: "The cooking soup" or "The soup cooking"?

Tags: sentence-construction, attributives

> 1. The **cooking soup** on the stove got burnt.
> 2. The **soup cooking** on the stove got burnt.

I think in the first there must be 'cooked' in the place of 'cooking'.

Please explain the difference in meanings of these sentences.

Comment: You should use a gerund to describe the state of the noun and therefore "*the soup cooking*"

Answer (score 1):

**The cooking soup on the stove got burnt.** is incorrect. In this sentence, you use a verb that acts like an adverb, which is perfectly fine but obscures the point of the sentence.

The main reason that **The soup cooking on the stove got burnt.** would be better is that it is more accurate to the situation. The second sentence tells you that the soup is cooking on the stove. The first one may be interpreted as soup called “cooking soup” sitting on the stove burnt.

Also, it would be more appropriate to use *was* or *became* rather that *got* because got usually means acquired or obtained.

Comment: I agree that the second is better, but would not go so far as to deem the first "incorrect." Also, I cannot agree that _became burnt_ would be better than [_got burnt_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=became+burnt%2Cgot+burnt&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).